# ¿Cómo puedo redondear un número a un solo decimal?

Tags: python, float, redondeo

Necesito aproximar un resultado en una aplicación que estoy creando, aun no puedo lograrlo si alguien puede ayudarme a salir de este problema. estoy utilizando qt creator python 3 y pyqt5

**Por ejemplo al poner el valor 2 en spinbox y spinbox_2 me da como resultado 1.6666666 y necesito que queda como resultado 1.7 mm**

Adjunto codigo del lanzador alarma.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from alarma_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class ventanaprincipal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ventanaprincipal,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.cuando_spinBox_2_valueChanged)
        self.spinBox_2.valueChanged.connect(self.cuando_SpinBox_valueChanged)



    def cuando_SpinBox_valueChanged(self, value):
        self.resultado.setText(str(((value * 10)/24) * self.spinBox.value()))

    def cuando_spinBox_2_valueChanged(self, value):
        self.resultado.setText(str(value + self.spinBox_2.value()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventanaprincipal = ventanaprincipal()
    ventanaprincipal.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo he entendido, en realidad lo que deseas es redondear el resultado de la operación (el cual muestras como texto en un `QLabel` o similar) a un solo decimal. Tienes varias opciones, entre ellas:

- Formatear la cadena con `str.format`:

  ```
  self.resultado.setText("{0:.1f}".format(((value * 10)/24) * self.spinBox.value())
  ```
- Formatear la cadena con literales de cadena formateados (Python >= 3.6)

  ```
  self.resultado.setText(f"{((value * 10) / 24) * self.spinBox.value():.1f}"
  ```

  Tanto en el caso de `str.format` como de f-string se usa el llamado [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). Para forzar que se muestre un solo decimal se usa `.1f`, dónde el entero es el número de decimales.
- Redondear el `float` previamente con el builtin [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

  ```
  self.resultado.setText(str(round(((value * 10)/24) * self.spinBox.value(), 1)))
  ```

  `round` recibe como primer argumento el número y como segundo el número de decimales que deseamos tras el redondeo. Si este argumento es `None` o no se le pasa se redondea al entero más cercano.

Ten en cuenta que puedes sufrir el [típico problema de la representación de decimales por la aritmética de coma flotante](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Si la precisión es muy importante, podrías usar [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Comment: gracias por tu pronta respuesta, con la ultima opcion me sale el siguiente error self.resultado.setText(str(round((value * 10)/24) * self.spinBox.value()), 1)
TypeError: setText(self, str): too many arguments

Comment: @BrunoOviedo era un error con la posición de un paréntesis, creo que ahora está bién.

Comment: excelente ahora si funciona, disculpa podrias decirme que función cumple el numero 1 al final del código, estoy recien empezando en este lenguaje muchas gracias

Comment: Es el segundo argumento de `round`, no es más que el numero de decimales que queremos tras el redondeo.

Comment: gracias nuevamente